# strlen() keeps adding p2 length value to p1 length

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to C++11 and currently learning on C-style character string. I use `strlen()` to retrieve the length of the C-string, however it keeps adding up the length of `p2` to `p1` (while it should be showing correctly individual length of each one).

[image: Screenshot_1]

[image: Screenshot_2]

[image: Screenshot_3]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Your arrays of `char` are not terminated with a zero value.  So the calls of `strlen()` have undefined behaviour.    Bear in mind that the character that prints as zero on screen (`'0'`) does not have a numeric value of zero (that is achieved by `'\0'`).   Your arrays have no characters with value `'\0'`.   `strlen()` looks for the numeric zero, and has undefined behaviour if it is not in the array.

Comment: char arrays and String class in cpp are two different things, Char arrays are terminated with null or '\0' or with 0 only. But String class in cpp handles the termination itself, no user provided termincation is needed.

Comment: [ask] - please include the code and the output as text rather than images. That makes it easier for others to try running/tweaking your code or to quote parts of it in a comment/answer.

Comment: Thank you Anton for the advice. I would include the code next time. Thank you Peter and quidstone for explaining right into the point! It did solve my problem!

Comment: Welcome Chris, going forward, don't post pictures of text, post the text itself (indented by 4-spaces so it formats as code). That way, as your questions get more difficult, others can compile your code and verify/validate your results, and enlist the aid of a debugger or memory use/error check to help answer your question. (obviously here that isn't the case....)

Answer (score 2):

When a character array is initialized by `char char_array[] = "01"`, the terminating NULL character is appended automatically. But when the array is initialized by `char char_array[] = {'0','1'}`, the terminating NULL character is not appended automatically and you have to add it manually. If you don't, `strlen` may output incorrect results.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  char p1[]={'0','1','\0'};
  char p2[]={'0','0','1','\0'};
  char p3[]="01";
  cout<<strlen(p1)<<" "<<p1<<endl<<strlen(p2)<<" "<<p2<<endl<<strlen(p3)<<" "<<p3<<endl;
}
```

Output

```
2 01
3 001
2 01
```

Comment: You answered exactly what I came for ahaha xD thank you so very much. Did try to upvote but I'm too new to have it displayed on your scores..

Comment: Happy to help, Chris!

Comment: @ChrisCao Important thing to note: null terminator is `'\0'` or `0` without single quotes.

Comment: Important thing without it -- passing `p1` or `p2` not contained a *nul-terminating* character to `strlen` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. (no:... `"strlen may output incorrect results"` about it `:)`